# Maven Build Compilation Error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-dep-mgt

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module Maven project in one root project I just want to add another maven module in the root project which contains many module, so after calling the parent from the pom.xml child  I get the following error:

parent pom:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-dep-mgt (default) on project calender: Found Dependency errors.
        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:analyze-dep
        -mgt (default) on project calender: Found Dependency errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

analyze-dep-mgt is a mojo which detects whenever there are dependency mismatches during the final resolution of the build. (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-dep-mgt-mojo.html)

There is likely to be a problem with your dependencies. Check this documentation for more info on how to structure your poms. (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

I recently had this error when adding a new dependency in which a transitive dependency was causing the same goal fail. Using an older version of the dependency resolved the issue.